# AVAudioPlayer not playing m4a or mp3 filetype from a website

Tags: ios, swift, url, audio, avaudioplayer

I am trying to locate a URL which is only pure .m4a sound with my application. I have the URL to the audio and theoretically download it. Then, with the downloaded fileURL to the sound, I try to play it with the AVAudioPlayer, yet it does not play any sound. Here is my code:

In the URL retrieval function, I call: (urls defined as a `URL(string: url)`, url being the retrieve URL string)

```
downloadSound(url: urls!)
```

Here is my downloadSound() function:

```
func downloadSound(url:URL){

    var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self](URL, response, error) -> Void in
        self?.playSound(url: URL!)
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

And lastly the playSound function:

```
func playSound(url:URL) {
    print("The url is \(url)")
    let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    player.play()
```

Everything is being called as the `print("The url is \(url)")` returns me the path of the file (I am not actually able to track the file, however).

Here is the general path of the sound on the simulator:

`file:///Users/[...]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/116C311A-C7F3-44EC-9762-2FAA0F9FE966/data/Containers/Data/Application/60BFCDE7-AC02-4196-8D1A-24EC646C4622/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_7VDpsV.tmp`

Whereas running it on a phone returns:

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C75C1F1D-77E9-4795-9A38-3F0756D30547/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_T1XlPb.tmp`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I choosed an alternative solution as app doc said:

> A file URL for the temporary file. Because the file is temporary, you
> must either open the file for reading or move it to a permanent
> location in your app’s sandbox container directory before returning
> from this delegate method.

The idea is just to copy from tmp directory to document directory and play from document directory.

Create a member variable:

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Now implement your **downloadSound** method as below:

```
func downloadSound(url:URL){
    let docUrl:URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
    let desURL = docUrl.appendingPathComponent("tmpsong.m4a")
    var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self](URLData, response, error) -> Void in
        do{
            let isFileFound:Bool? = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: desURL.path)
            if isFileFound == true{
                  print(desURL) //delete tmpsong.m4a & copy

                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: desURL.path)
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URLData!, to: desURL)

            } else {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URLData!, to: desURL)
            }
            let sPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: desURL!)
            self?.player = sPlayer
            self?.player.prepareToPlay()
            self?.player.play()

        }catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
            
        })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

This is just a sample solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I did not know you had to save temp files before applying them!