# Swift: File Manager file location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making small audio mobile application.

I stores mp3 files in my app location folder:

```
let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)
...
let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

        for song in songPath
        ...
```

So my destination folder is:

> file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0444F701-24A0-4500-A03C-2BB885966A63/MusicBox.app/M.I.A.%20-%20Paper%20Planes.mp3

Now I am trying to download music from FTP using FileManager:

```
if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/mp3/2221/08.%20Driver%20(vs.%20djalien).mp3") {
  let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

 // destination file url
    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
    print("destinationUrl is :",destinationUrl)
```

Right now my destination folder is:

> destinationUrl is :
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/382E4E58-7939-467B-9315-D5315CF14483/Applications/08.%20Driver%20(vs.%20djalien).mp3

How to set the same destination folder in (Bundle.main.resourcePath!)?

It's my first application in Swift and I do not quite understand FileManager location.

Comment: You can't write to the bundle; it is read only. You can write to your applications documents directory.

Comment: Unrelated but there is `let folderURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!`. And `.applicationDirectory` is probably mistaken. The variable name implies you mean `.documentDirectory`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391623/avaudioplayer-not-playing-m4a-or-mp3-filetype-from-a-website